# If one Arithmetic Mean (A.M) $A$ and the two Geometric Means (G.M.'s) $G_1$ and $G_2$ are inserted between two given positive numbers, prove that:

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If one Arithmetic Mean (A.M) $A$ and the two Geometric Means (G.M.'s) $G_1$ and $G_2$ are inserted between two given positive numbers, prove that:
$$\dfrac {{G_1}^2}{G_2} + \dfrac {{G_2}^2}{G_1}=2A$$

My Attempt:
Let $a$ and $b$ are any two positive numbers. Then,
$$A=\dfrac {a+b}{2}$$
Also,
$a, G_1, G_2, b$ are in G.P.
so, $\dfrac {G_1}{a}=\dfrac {G_2}{G_1}=\dfrac {b}{G_2}$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: One arithmetic mean and two geometric means of what? What makes the geometric means different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\implies G_1^2=aG_2,G_2^2=bG_1$$

$$\implies\dfrac{G_1^2}{G_2}+\dfrac{G_2^2}{G_1}=a+b=2A$$

Answer (score 0):

let $$\frac{G_1}{a}=\frac{G_2}{G_1}=\frac{b}{G_2}=t$$
then
$$G_1=at$$
$$G_2=at^2$$
$$b=t^3a$$
then we have the equation
$$\frac{a^2t^2}{t^2a}+\frac{t^4 a^2}{at}=2A$$
can you finish?
simplifying we get
$$a+t^3a=a+b$$ and remember that $$b=t^3a$$